# Git fetch does not show remote branch in for-each-ref

Tags: git

I have a remote branch `feature/test2`. I want to fetch it. I run:

```
git fetch origin feature/test2
```

And I get:

```
From <URL>
 * branch            feature/test2 -> FETCH_HEAD
```

But when I run:

```
 git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/remotes/origin/feature/test2
```

I don't see `feature/test2`. Only if I run `get fetch`, and then the command above, I'll see `feature/test2`. Why is that?

Comment: (1) What version of Git are you running? (2) What is the result of `git config --get remote.origin.fetch`?

Comment: The reasons to check both of these are: (1) If your Git predates Git 1.8.4, it won't create remote-tracking names automatically for this kind of fetch. An upgrade to modern Git will fix it. (2) If you have `remote.origin.fetch` set as for a single-branch clone instead of the default, your Git won't create other remote-tracking names. (In this case, the fact that running `git fetch` with no arguments works suggests to me that the problem is from case 1 rather than case 2.)

Comment: @torek Hey, you're right. I've become so used to this very useful feature that I forgot it hasn't always been that way. I'll add the precision as a warning, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When you fetch a branch, git updates the corresponding ref in your local, which we call **a remote-tracking branch**. It mirrors the last known state of this remote ref.

You can see these branches with `git branch -r`

But these are not your *local* branches, which your `for-each-ref` command asks for.

*-- (The following assumes you're using a git version > 1.8.3) --*

To create a local counterpart to your remote `origin/feature/test2`, check it out

```
git checkout feature/test2
```

and git will recognize the name as one one your remote-tracking branches (since you already fetched it earlier) and set the link for push/pull operations.

At this point only will it appear in the output of your `for-each-ref` command.

Answer (score 1):

It lists **all** branches not merged into origin/release_15.0.0

```
git for-each-ref --no-merged=origin/release_15.0.0 --format="%(committerdate:short) %(authorname)  %(refname:short)" --sort=committerdate **refs/remotes/origin**
```

It lists **local** branches not merged into origin/release_15.0.0

```
git for-each-ref --no-merged=origin/release_15.0.0 --format="%(committerdate:short) %(authorname)  %(refname:short)" --sort=committerdate **refs/heads**
```

Comment: This was a lifesaver for me. Thanks!