# git fetch not fetching a remote branch on a fresh clone on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.7 (Maipo)

Tags: postgresql, git, github, fetch, redhat

On RedHat server 7.7

I ran the following commands.

```
git clone https://github.com/postgres/postgres.git
cd postgres
git remote add upstream https://github.com/postgres/postgres.git
git fetch upstream REL_12_STABLE
```

The output was as follows:

```
From https://github.com/postgres/postgres
 * branch            REL_12_STABLE -> FETCH_HEAD
```

instead of

```
From https://github.com/postgres/postgres
* branch REL_12_STABLE -> FETCH_HEAD
* [new branch] REL_12_STABLE -> upstream/REL_12_STABLE
```

If i run the git branch –r command, we DO NOT see an extra upstream/REL_12_STABLE entry

While on RedHat 8 every thing works fine.

Comment: The Git version on your RH7.7 system must predate Git 1.8.4. Use `git --version` to see what version you have. Your Git version on RH8 is presumably less ancient (anything before about 2.17 at this point is really old!).

Comment: See also [Git fetch does not show remote branch in for-each-ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59824284/1256452) (I'm hesitant to close as duplicate here though).

Comment: ... and what is the output of `git --version`? (There is another possibility but let's see that first)

Comment: Thank you very much. The git version on RedHat 7 was very old. Upgrading solved the problem. Kindly add the latest git binaries path to $PATH variable. In my case it was /usr/libexec/git-core

Comment: Rather than adding "SOLVED" to your title, perhaps it would be better to encourage @torek to post an answer that you can mark as the correct solution, or to [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) this question?

Comment: Yes, you must either post and accept an answer or delete your post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently (per comments) the Git version on RH7.7 was quite old, predating Git 1.8.4.  (A google search suggests that it is in fact 1.8.3.1.)  Very old versions of Git like this simply fail to create-or-update remote-tracking names like `upstream/REL_12_STABLE` when using this form of `git fetch`.

There are several cures or workarounds.  Here are my top-two:

- Installing a newer Git version will fix it.  (Note that a custom Git might live in a different directory from the system Git.  This can be messy, but is generally supposed to work.  You may need to adjust your `PATH` setting.)
- Running `git fetch upstream` instead of `git fetch upstream REL_12_STABLE` will work around it, although this has the disadvantage of fetching everything rather than just the one branch.